# How to parse and validate a JsonRecord with io-ts?

Tags: fp-ts

I need to parse a string that contains json.  I need to ensure that the output is a `JsonRecord` rather than a json primitive.

I have tried to use `fp-ts` and `io-ts` for this.  So far I know that `t.UnknownRecord.decode` will return an `Either`.  This will be `left` for a primitive and `right` for a record.  I'm not sure how to compose this along with `parseJSON`.  When I try I get type errors.  See the comment between the tests below.

```
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as t from "io-ts";

const onLeft = () => "NO";
const onRight = () => "YES";

describe("parsing strings of json", () => {
  it("should return a right for a json record", () => {
    const record: E.JsonRecord = { banana: "yellow fruit" };
    expect(t.UnknownRecord.decode(record)).toEqual(E.right(record));
  });

  it("should not return a right for a json primitive", () => {
    const primitive: E.Json = "banana is a yellow fruit";
    expect(t.UnknownRecord.decode(primitive)).not.toEqual(
      E.right(primitive)
    );
  });

  it("should say YES for a string containing a json record", () => {
    expect(
      pipe(
        E.parseJSON('{"banana":"yellow fruit"}', E.toError),
        E.chain(t.UnknownRecord.decode),
        E.fold(onLeft, onRight)
      )
    ).toEqual("YES");
  });

  //  Argument of type 'Either<Error, Json>' is not assignable to parameter of type     'Either<Errors, unknown>'.
  //    Type 'Left<Error>' is not assignable to type 'Either<Errors, unknown>'.
  //      Type 'Left<Error>' is not assignable to type 'Left<Errors>'.
  //        Type 'Error' is missing the following properties from type 'Errors': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.

  it("should say NO for a string containing a json primitive", () => {
    expect(
      pipe(
        E.parseJSON('"banana is a yellow fruit"', E.toError),
        E.chain(t.UnknownRecord.decode),
        E.fold(onLeft, onRight)
      )
    ).toEqual("NO");
  });
});
```

Is it correct to try and use `chain` here or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some advice I now know that the answer is as follows:

```
import * as f from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
...
it('should say YES for a string containing a json record', () => {
  expect(
    f.pipe(
      E.parseJSON('{"banana":"yellow fruit"}', E.toError),
      E.chain(f.flow(t.UnknownRecord.decode, E.mapLeft(E.toError))),
      E.fold(onLeft, onRight)
    )
  ).toEqual('YES');
});

it('should say NO for a string containing a json primitive', () => {
  expect(
    f.pipe(
      E.parseJSON('"banana is a yellow fruit"', E.toError),
      E.chain(f.flow(t.UnknownRecord.decode, E.mapLeft(E.toError))),
      E.fold(onLeft, onRight)
    )
  ).toEqual('NO');
});
```