# How to lookup the value for a key in type Json (fp-ts)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fp-ts

I can extract a value from a json string in an Option with this code:

##### Code that works

```js
import { identity, pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as E from "fp-ts/Either";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/Record";

const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  (x) =>
    E.tryCatch(
      () => JSON.parse(x),
      (reason) => new Error(String(reason))
    ),
  O.fromEither,
  O.chain(R.lookup("a"))
);
console.log(a);
```

The type coming out of the `E.tryCatch` call is `Either<Error, any>` and `R.lookup` seems to accept `any`.

##### Code that doesn't work

Instead of using `JSON.parse` directly, I would like to use [`parse`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Json.ts.html#parse) from the `Json` module in `fp-ts`.

```js
import { identity, pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as J from "fp-ts/lib/Json";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/Record";
const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  J.parse,
  O.fromEither,
  O.chain(R.lookup("a"))  <-- Error
);
```

Trying to use =R.lookup= on =Json= gives the following error:

```
Argument of type '<A>(r: Record<string, A>) => Option<A>' 
is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Json) => Option<Json>'
```

I guess it is because `Json` can have lots of values (`boolean | number | string | null | JsonArray | JsonRecord`) and only `JsonRecord` would be compatible with `Record`.

##### Question

How can I convert `Json` to `Record` (or anything letting me "lookup" value for key)? Or perhaps narrow my `Json` object to `JsonRecord`?

##### What I tried

Following the `zipObject` example for [`fromFoldableMap`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Record.ts.html#fromfoldablemap), I tried to do something like below without success:

```
import { identity, pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as J from "fp-ts/lib/Json";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/Record";
const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  J.parse,
  O.fromEither,
  O.map((kvs) => R.fromFoldableMap(last<J.Json>(), R.Foldable)(kvs, identity)), <-- Not working
  O.chain(R.lookup("a"))
);
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to parse and validate a JsonRecord with io-ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902287/how-to-parse-and-validate-a-jsonrecord-with-io-ts)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. I did read it yesterday but since a specific Json module was added to fp-ts, I still have the feeling that this problem can be solved without needing io-ts.

Comment: Ah I posted my answer before seeing that someone else had mentioned `io-ts`. I went ahead and showed how to get things working without it in my answer, but I tried to make an argument for using that library. I hope my reasoning is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there's an error is because the `Json` type isn't necessarily assignable to a `Record`. For example, the string `'11'` would be valid input to `JSON.parse` or `J.parse` and would result in the `number` `11`. That number cannot be used like a `Record`. It could likewise be an array, or a string, or null, etc. You'll need to further parse the returned value before you can use it with `R.lookup`.

The most straightforward thing I can think of to solve that problem is to add `io-ts`* into the mix.

Simplest I suspect is something like:

```
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as J from "fp-ts/lib/Json";
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/Record";
import * as t from "io-ts";

const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  J.parse,
  E.chainW(t.UnknownRecord.decode), // Different Error type so chainW
  O.fromEither,
  O.chain(R.lookup("a"))
);
```

If you're going to leverage `io-ts` and you know the rough shape of the object you're parsing, then you can improve on this approach with something like:

```
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as J from "fp-ts/lib/Json";
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import * as t from "io-ts";

const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
// Here you can define the exact shape of what you
// think J.parse will have returned.
const schema = t.type({
  a: t.number
});
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  J.parse,
  // Decode will then match that shape or return a `E.left` if it fails to.
  E.chainW(schema.decode),
  O.fromEither,
  // The type of innerA is number and no need to do `lookup`
  // because the entire shape of the object has been validated
  O.map(({ a: innerA }) => innerA)
);
```

For absolute completeness just using `fp-ts` I think you could get something working like:

```
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as J from "fp-ts/lib/Json";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/Record";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";

const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
// Note that the return type here is going to be `Option<Json>` which
// may still be difficult to work with in your code for the same reason
// that you couldn't use `R.lookup` directly. Parsing with `io-ts` will
// give you easier types to work with.
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  J.parse,
  O.fromEither,
  O.chain((json) => {
    // This is basically just inlining what `io-ts` would do for you so
    // I again would recommend that library.
    if (typeof json === "object" && json !== null && !(json instanceof Array)) {
      return pipe(json, R.lookup("a"));
    } else {
      return O.none;
    }
  })
);
```

The last thing I'll mention is that, if you really want this function to work with as little changes as possible and you're ok with the `O.Option<J.Json>` return type, and if you can assert that the string will always be a JSON object, and you really don't want to use `io-ts`, you could achieve what you want with a type assertion like:

```
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as J from "fp-ts/lib/Json";
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/Record";
const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
const a = pipe(
  jsonString,
  J.parse,
  O.fromEither,
  // Again this is unsafe because the value might be an Array or a primitive
  // value. You're basically just escaping from the type system.
  O.map((json: J.Json): J.JsonRecord => json as J.JsonRecord),
  O.chain(R.lookup("a"))
);
```

But I don't recommend this approach as I think it will be difficult to work with the return value and you open yourself up to errors if the input json string isn't an object.

---

*[`io-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) is a library from the same people that make `fp-ts` that is used for validating the shape of `unknown` data in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a really great detailled answer and I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**You could just parse the string right when you get it and use the parsed object in your program**.

```
const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
var parsedJsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log( "Parsed JSON: ", parsedJsonString );
console.log( "a:", parsedJsonString.a );
```

**To be a little bit safer, you could check if it is really a json string like this:**

```
function isJsonString(jsonString){
    try {
        JSON.parse(jsonString);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

const jsonString = '{"a": 1}';
var isValidJson = isJsonString( jsonString );
if( isValidJson ){
    var parsedJsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    console.log( "Parsed JSON: ", parsedJsonString );
    console.log( "a:", parsedJsonString.a );
}else{
    console.log("jsonString is not a valid json");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However this question is specific to the fp-ts library.

Comment: Oh, i see. Sorry for my misunderstanding.